# Block other websites from being used

Tags: php

I have a short url website where I try to block all but one specific domain from being used in url shortening. I use the code bellow to try to block any other domain. It's been fine until I noticed that a few people have managed to get some bad urls past it and into the database to use in phishing.

For example they have entered the following spam urls into the database and managed to make them redirect users to phishing urls.

Is there some way to stop this?

**SPAM URLS**

```
1: http://example.com@spamerurl.com/Jtn3yrl.png 
2: http://spamurl.com/6004a8c964d05?example.com
3: https://together.atexample.com/
```

**CODE**

```
function isValidUrl($url)
{
    /* validate url */
    $url = getBaseUrl($url);

    if (!strpos($url, "."))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    $urlregex = "^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?[a-z0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-z0-9+\$_-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$";
    if (eregi($urlregex, $url))
    {
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}


function getBaseUrl($url)
{
     $urlExp = explode("/", $url);
     return $urlExp[0] . "//" . $urlExp[2];
}
    
function deny($url)
{
     $strAllow = 'example.com'; 
     $strBase  = getBaseUrl($url);
     if(strpos($url, $strAllow) === false)
     {
        return true;
     }
                    
}
```

Comment: What exactly does `getBaseUrl` do? In what way is it currently not reliable, examples?

Comment: (“Reliable” would possibly mean, that you have to take punycode into account as well, resp. do a punycode decode, before you make the comparison.)

Comment: for example i saw that someone has managed to use a bitly.com and not the domain.com adress in the submission form and i wonder how that would be possible ?

Comment: What’s the purpose of using that `getBaseUrl` here, if you then don’t actually use the variable `$strBase`? And what are your exact input values here? Rather than showing an incomplete snippet and then giving much verbal explanation that is still vague, please provide a proper [mre] for problems like this.

Comment: i have update the question with what i think you asked for ?

Comment: So they tricked you here, by putting the domain you want to allow, into that first URL as a _user name_. You should not roll your own function that tries to take the URL apart, but use https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php - that would have realized that `example.com` is a user name here, and that the host is `spamerurl.com`

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using a regular expression, use a dedicated URL parser. [PHP has one built in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php).

```
$urls = [];
$urls[] = 'http://example.com@spamerurl.com/Jtn3yrl.png';
$urls[] = 'http://spamurl.com/6004a8c964d05?example.com';
$urls[] = 'https://together.atexample.com/';
$urls[] = 'http://example.com';
$urls[] = 'https://www.example.com';

foreach($urls as $url) {
  $host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
  $ok = in_array($host, ['example.com', 'www.example.com']) ? 'OK' : 'not OK';
  echo "${url} has host ${host}, which is ${ok}\n";
}
```

Edit: apologies to @CBroe—I didn't see your comment recommending the use of `parse_url`—if you post it as an answer I would request OP to accept that, rather than this answer. You are right that the `example.com` portion is indeed a user name in the first example.